# Is it possible to apply news strip in android app

Tags: android, rss, feed

I have a idea of making a news app in which breaking news or top stories will be seen at the bottom of the android phone just like in TV.
It will not occupy whole screen instead of it will show only headlines in a continuous moving news strip.
I know it will be needing RSS feeds from different news website but i want to know the procedure of making the app means the "blueprint" of the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Widget is not a good idea as it does not support animation, you can only update the widgets periodically.

If you need your ticker to be available always on top of all application. Then you could run a service and show a dialog activity. But that will send the current app to the background. Here is the solution:

The [standOut](https://github.com/pingpongboss/StandOut) library by pingpong boss will help you achieve it.

[image]

Comment: what i want know that which type of predefined widget and layout would be preferable and would it be in form of a dialog format or whole activity format???

Comment: These are not widgets...you can customise it to look like a dialog or an activity.

Answer (score 0):

you would need to create a android desktop widget to do this. This [link here](http://steveliles.github.io/my_first_android_app_desktop_widget.html) should be useful. There also more code samples for ticker apps like [this one](https://github.com/markmarijnissen/stockticker).
To position at the bottom of the screen exactly may not be possible without playing with the android OS itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this by a background service and a system overlay view, thus by making ticker visible all the time not only in homescreen

Comment: what i want know that which type of predefined widget and layout would be preferable and would it be in form of a dialog format or whole activity format???

Comment: It totaly depends on your requirement. If it is simple textview , you could try with simple Texview/ TextSwitcher etc.